# CRM 2013 Limit the date field

Tags: javascript, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have 3 date and time fields (its date only).
But I want to limit the user not to be able to select future date.
I mean dates after today's couldn't be selected in the date picker.
How can I do it?

Comment: I think it is possible to do it with java. Do you have the java code for it? Because I have searched and I couldn't find that.

Now I fill a field with current date then with a business rule I compare the other fields with the current date to be smaller that that.

But if I can fine the java code to compare the date with java it's absolutely better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crm datetime field doesn't support this type of functionality. You'll need to create your own html webresource and use a well-known library / control such as jquery datepicker. 
Once you have the resource in place syncing the picker value with the hidden datetime value should be relatively easy using the form onload and onsave events.

Comment: You don't need an html webresource, you just need an OnChange javascript in the date fields and compare the actual date with the date picked, if the date picked is greater then you just clean the field. This is a simple way and it shouldn't be that complex to require a webresource.

Comment: @Sxntk He's looking for a proactive approach so future dates are not selectable. This is not possible using crm datetime. He's not interested in alerting and reverting to initial date values

Comment: As part as our daily deveploment, you should negociate that requirements, the cost of maintain that webresource vs a js is pretty high. Crm day a day evolve so if you can support something as native as possible do it.

Comment: @Sxntk He is right. I think it is possible to do it with java. Do you have the java code for it? Because I have searched and I couldn't find that.

Now I fill a field with current date then with a business rule I compare the other fields with the current date to be smaller that that.

But if I can fine the java code to compare the date with java it's absolutely better.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a validator, either in plugin or JavaScript (or business rules), or perhaps both. 
JS only works in the forms but has the possibility to give a prettier error message, with the business rules you can have a valitation which gives messages inline. If you only add data using the GUI, it might be enough to just use JS/business rules but if data can come any other way I would secure it with a plugin as well.

The validator is pretty simple, retrieve the field and compare it with a date object today. It could be a bit worse if there are a lot of timezones involved, we don't like timezones....